# How to impute data depending on a class

Tags: r

Hello everyone I'm looking for an elegant way to impute NA's in my dataset:

```
Sex Age
M   20
M   21
F   30
M   NA
F   26
F   29
F   NA
```

I'd like to impute different age mean for each sex. I assume that age distribution for female and male slightly differs. Unfortunately I see no possibility to do it without creating new column and then putting in again into the dataset. Even though I go this way it doesn't work and I think i'm overthinking the problem:

```
    males <- train[train[, "Sex"]=="male", ]
    females <- train[train[, "Sex"]=="female", ] 

    mf <- mean(train$Age, na.rm = TRUE)  
    mm <- mean(train$Age, na.rm = TRUE)

    train[train$Age == NA & train$Sex == "male", "Age"] <- mf 

    Error in '[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, males$Age == NA & males$Sex == "male",  
    : missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
```

May I ask for any tips?

Comment: You have to use `is.na(train$Age)` to check for missing values.

Comment: Thank you, I'm already aware of it neverthless it's not the problem's clue.

Comment: @Tom - you're using `train$Age == NA` - try `is.na(train$Age)` as shown in user2974951 answer

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get the logic. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a value is `NA` in R you have to use the `is.na(something)` function. Comparing directly `something==NA` or `something=="NA"` will throw an error.

```
mm <- mean(train$Age[train$Sex=="male"], na.rm = TRUE)
mf <- mean(train$Age[train$Sex=="female"] , na.rm = TRUE)

train$Age[is.na(train$Age) & train$Sex=="male"] <- mm
train$Age[is.na(train$Age) & train$Sex=="female"] <- mf
```

Comment: Please provide some context to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want more plausible values than just the mean for each missing value, you might consider the package `mice`:

```
df_old <- data.frame(Sex = c(rep("M", 500), rep("F", 500)),
                 Age = round(c(rnorm(500, 35, 2), rnorm(500, 25, 2))))

df_NA <- data.frame(Sex = sample(c("M", "F"), 10, rep = T),
                    Age = NA)

df_old %>% 
  group_by(Sex) %>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(Age))
```

Here are the means for both genders:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Sex    Mean
  <fct> <dbl>
1 F      24.9
2 M      34.9
```

Now combining both dataframes and imputing the values using `mice`:

```
df <- rbind(df_old, df_NA)

library(mice)
df_imp <- complete(mice(df, m=5, maxit=50, meth='pmm', seed=500), 1)
cbind(tail(df, n = 10), tail(df_imp, n = 10))
```

We used the *predictive mean matching* algortihm to impute the missing values. There are several other algortihs available (`?mice`).
The last line shows you the imputed vlaues:

```
       Sex Age Sex Age
1001   M  NA   M  30
1002   F  NA   F  24
1003   M  NA   M  33
1004   M  NA   M  33
1005   F  NA   F  25
1006   M  NA   M  35
1007   M  NA   M  36
1008   M  NA   M  36
1009   M  NA   M  37
1010   F  NA   F  27
```

Comment: It is what I was looking for in a broader context, It'll be really helpful for me in the future, thank you!

Comment: But does the regular mice function in the first step differentiate that they're two different groups or it takes the whole population firstly and then bases the prediction on two parameters? Does it even make difference?

Comment: Excellent! I really appreciate it